# REGEX PREG_MATCH_ALL

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Hi all I tried to understand a bit how regular expression works and with some pretty easy example i think i quiet understood a bit. 
A person asked me to grab some parts of text from an HTML page.
The various part i have to grab are all between a string that is like this var x (where x is a nuber) = ' text text text text ' ;
so i tried something like this:

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]\s\=\s\'(.*?)\'\s\;/", $file, $matches);
print_r($matches);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
   echo $matches[1][$i]."<br>";
}
```

If im not wrong i'm saying to grab eveything between a part of text that starts with a number, a space, an equal sign, an other space, a single quote, and that ends wih a single quote, a space and a semicolon.
Am i wrong? guess i am cause it gives me empty array

Comment: Your understanding of the regex placeholders is correct. If it applies to your actual input, only you can tell. You haven't shown the source here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With out some sample text from your html file that you are feeding to `preg_match_all()` it's impossible for us to provide you with a working regex...

Never-the-less this may help you.

**Your code**

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]\s\=\s\'(.*?)\'\s\;/", $file, $matches);
print_r($matches);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
   echo $matches[1][$i]."<br>";
}
```

The first thing I notice is that in your `for` loop you use `count($matches[0])` and then when echoing from within the loop you use `$matches[1]`. While it isn't necessarily a problem in the case of `preg_match_all`, why didn't you just use `count($matches[1])` all the way through?

The second thing that I have to ask is: have you opened the file and retrieved the plain text? Something like:

```
$file = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.html'); //For example
```

Okay, now for your regex...

`[0-9]` Will match a single number

`\s` Will match any white space character so: SPACE, TAB, NEW_LINE, etc.

`\=` Matches `=`

`\'` Matches `'`

`\;` Matches `;`

`(.*?)` Matches AND Captures any character *zero or more* times

**NOTE:** The question mark in the regex is important as it will stop matching at the earliest opportunity as will be elaborated on later.

## Going Forward

While your regex will work and give you what you want it isn't the easiest thing to read in the world.

To match: `0 = 'something to be captured in here' ;`

You can use: `/\d = '(.*?)' ;/`

There's no need to escape `=`, `'`, and `;`. Also `\d` is an alias of `[0-9]` so can be used interchangeably (but `\d` is less characters and easier to read). You also don't need to use `\s` you can just type a space (unless you specifically need to include other white space characters such as those mentioned earlier.

An example use would be:

```
$string = "some text before 0 = 'captured by regex' ; some text afterwards...";

preg_match_all("/\d = '(.*?)' \;/", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
/**
Output from var_dump

    array(2) {
      [0]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(27) "0 = 'captured by regex' ;"
      }
      [1]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(19) "captured by regex"
      }
    }
*/
```

You could then iterate through the matched text like so:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++){
    echo $matches[1][$i], "<br>";
}
```

### About the question mark

Just to clarify the point about the `?` and why it **IS** needed.

In general the regex will continue through the source text as far as is possible which can in some circumstances (this one included) pose a problem.

If you were to use the regex without a `?` - `(.*)` instead of `(.*?)` - then the regex would match from the first `X = '` all the way to the very last `' ;` which would inevitably include several of the capture groups you were planning on matching. If you use the `?` however it tells the regex to stop at the first instance of (in this case) `' ;`.

You can see this working simply by adding `' ;` to the end of `$string` in my code and trying with and without the `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Thnk everyone for the answer, I solved on my own.
I couldnt copy the text i needed cause was full of company's name, addresses, email and phone number.
I tried one of those regex test online by copying the html inside and i noticed that the part of text that i needed was full of \n \n \n so i wasnt able to capture it(i didnt know that i had to add the "s" after the closing slash "/" )
Thnk for the long answer and it gave me more aknowledge about the argument, thnk!